# Integrate Google Map with Markers from HTTPrequest Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, titanium, appcelerator

Hi there I am Using appcelerator, and I want to integrate a map with an array of markers I am getting from a HTTPRequest...
I am effing lost, totally lost.

This is how the map looks like:

```
var mapview = Titanium.Map.createView({
    mapType: Titanium.Map.STANDARD_TYPE,
    region: {latitude:33.74511, longitude:-84.38993, 
            latitudeDelta:0.01, longitudeDelta:0.01},
    animate:true,
    regionFit:true,
    userLocation:true,
    annotations:[mountainView]
});
```

And I have the example of 1 marker hardcoded ...

```
var mountainView = Titanium.Map.createAnnotation({
    latitude:37.390749,
    longitude:-122.081651,
    title:"Appcelerator Headquarters",
    subtitle:'Mountain View, CA',
    pincolor:Titanium.Map.ANNOTATION_RED,
    animate:true,
    leftButton: '../images/appcelerator_small.png',
    myid:1 // CUSTOM ATTRIBUTE THAT IS PASSED INTO EVENT OBJECTS
});
```

So yo create the marker and in the annotations section you add it to the map, the thing here is that I am getting the markers from this:

```
var url = "http://myURLwithMyParameters";
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    onload: function(e) {
        // this function is called when data is returned from the server and available for use
        // this.responseText holds the raw text return of the message (used for text/JSON)
var result = this.responseText;
var xml = Ti.XML.parseString(result);
var items = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

var name = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("name");
var value = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("address");

var data = [];

for (var i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
  data.push({
        name: items.item[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].textContent,
        address: items.item[i].getElementsByTagName("address")[0].textContent 

   })
```

Does any one know how to integrate this? 
I think I must build the map in the same function as the markers, but I've tried several options and haven't found ANY example of this in the web.
Any clue would be very appreciated. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your data array is not filled with the data or what? If it is empty, define the array out side the onload function.

Comment: Why are you only getting name and address from the data?  Where are you getting the latitude and longitude for each item you push into the data array?

Answer (score 0):

If all you have is an address, you'll need to forward geocode those addresses to get lat/long coordinates. Those coords are required to place annotations on the map. Check the docs at [forwardGeocoder()](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Geolocation.forwardGeocoder-method.html). There's an example in the [KitchenSink](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/examples/geolocation.js#L443)